# Kotlin Android Firebase Database Hashmap Cast to Class

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, android-gridview

I am trying to get data from a firebase database.
The breakpoints show it is getting the data, but it looks like I am not properly assigning it to my class.

which causes this exception :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   Class

```
override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
    if (p0!!.exists()){
        val children = p0!!.children
        children.forEach {
            println(it.value.toString())
            var item : DashboardItem = it.value as DashboardItem
            println(item)
        }
    }
}
```

this is the DB export :

```
{
 "dashboard" : [ 
    { "name" : "News"}, 
    { "name" : "Chatroom"},
    { "name" : "Music"},
    { "name" : "Quotes"},
    { "name" : "Reminder"},
    { "name" : "Poll"},
    { "name" : "Suggestion"},
    { "name" : "LogOut"} ]  
}
```

the class object i want to create

```
data class DashboardItem(val name: String = "")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue : [`DataSnapshot#getValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue())  will return only `native types` as

```
Boolean
String
Long
Double
Map<String, Object> // closest to your object representation
List<Object>
```

where `Map<String, Object>` will be returned as object when requested hence the error when you apply explicit cast

So instead use [`DataSnapshot#getValue(Class<T> valueType)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) as

```
val item : DashboardItem = it.getValue(DashboardItem::class.java)
```

Comment: THANKS Mr Singh
val item : DashboardItem = it.getValue(DashboardItem::class.java)!!        
had to add !!

Comment: I am glad that i could help Mr. Kamta , happy coding