# error retrieving data from firebase with KOTLIN

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase, but I get:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.android.mlc.model.Usuario

I don't know why the cast fails:

```
private fun listarDatos() {

    databaseReference.child("Usuario").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Failed to load post.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            Log.w("Usuarios1", "mehe")
            for (UsuariosFirebase in dataSnapshot.children) {
                  listaUsuarios.add(UsuariosFirebase.value as Usuario) <--- ERROR
      

                arrayAdapterUusuario = ArrayAdapter<Usuario>(this@MainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaUsuarios)
                listaV_Usuarios.adapter = arrayAdapterUusuario
            }


        }
    })
}
```

Why can't I cast the value `UsuarioFireBase.value` to `Usuario`?

Comment: what is the type of `listaUsuarios`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Seems to be the same case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957319/kotlin-android-firebase-database-hashmap-cast-to-class

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your `UsuariosFirebase.value` returns a `Map<String, Object>`, which indeed can't be cast to `Usuario` as the error indicates.

To get the data from the `DataSnapshot` as a `Usuario` object, you will have to tell Firebase to do that conversion for you:

```
listaUsuarios.add(UsuariosFirebase.getValue<Usuario>())
```

Also see the documentation on [getting values  from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events).

---

The above requires that you have the [Kotlin extensions (KTX) for Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#kotlin+ktx) installed. If you're having a hard time making that work, you can also use this variant, which is a pretty direct rewrite of the Java code:

```
listaUsuarios.add(UsuariosFirebase.getValue(Usuario::class.java))
```

Comment: no type arguments expected for fun getValue: Any? ... im gonna cry

Comment: Can you try `listaUsuarios.add(UsuariosFirebase.getValue(Usuario::class.java))`? That's what I've seen used elsewhere, but my answer is based on what the documentation suggest.

Comment: yes, ty bro,  UsuariosFirebase.getValue(Usuario::class.java) works fine :)